# How can we write a parameterized query in ssrs report when we use Snowflake as data source

Tags: migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parameterized

I'm working on Sql server to Snowflake migration project,So i pointed ssrs reports to Snowflake data source and converting sql queries as per snowflake,but i'm not able to get how can we write queries for parameterized reports.Example select * from Student where Std_id=@id,want to convert to snowflake query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL variables:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html

or Snowflake Scripting Variables:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html

I think the SQL variables would be helpful in your case, but Snowflake Scripting variables would be more similar to your SQL Server @ variables.